# Free Logic Analyzer to decode 1-Wire

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, data-analysis, electronics

I bought a cheap 8 channel Logic Analyzer. They call it Saleae Logic Analyzer, but the hardware does not at all ressemble the [original Saleae Logic 8](https://eur.saleae.com/products/saleae-logic-8?variant=10963959349291).

I read that the Saleae software might still work with this device, but I'd like to be fair and use something else.

At the moment I'm experimenting with a DS18B20 temperature sensor, which uses the 1-Wire protocol. To have a look at those signals, I'd like to have a software that

- is [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis), [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source) preferred
- runs on Windows 10 x64 1909
- decodes 1-Wire protocol and hopefully some more
- ideally supports 8 channels, but at least 4 channels simultaneously
- can record at 4 Mbit/s (at least that's what I expect to get out of the 24 MHz chip)
- has virtually no limit on memory, so I can benefit of my overpowered machine
- allows me to save the recorded data
- works [offline](/questions/tagged/offline) with no Internet connection required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sigrok/Pulseview](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Main_Page) ([download](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Downloads)) is probably the tool of choice here.

Requirements:

- [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis): yes
- [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source) preferred: Gnu GPL v3
- [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10): yes, it seems to go down to Windows XP
- decodes 1-wire protocol: yes, and 116 other [protocols](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Protocol_decoders)
- supports at least 4 channels: yes
- ideally supports 8 channels: yes, and even up to 34 if you have the right [hardware](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Supported_hardware)
- can record at 4 MBit/s: yes, the settings allow up to 48 MBit/s
- has virtually no limit on memory: it can record 1T samples, that is 1.000.000 M samples
- allows me to save data: yes, as `.srzip` (session file format)
- works offline: yes

Here's a screenshot of some decoded 1-wire data:

[image: Pulseview screenshot decoding 1-wire data]

The installation and configuration is not exactly simple. First, understand that a lot of components work together here. We have:

- **Sigrok**, which seems to be the basis for all sorts of stuff. Usually you would not see anything of Sigrok.
- **Pulseview** is a GUI for Sigrok that focuses on logic analyzers.
- You also need **Zadig**, which provides the drivers for Sigrok.

So, first use Zadig. The cheap Chinese logic analyzer will be shown as "unknown device" first with no driver installed. Edit the name and install the driver, so it looks like this:

[image: Zadig driver installation]

Next, run PulseView and it should recognize a device. To decode a protocol, click the green-yellow button to add a protocol decoder.

[image]